# Retornar Json usando Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho 3 tabelas faço o inner join nelas , mas preciso retornar um json, só consegui retornando um select simples:

**Minha clausula Sql:**

```
SELECT publicacao.codPublicacao as codpublicacao,
       usuario.nome as nomeusuario,
       publicacao.categoria as categoria,
       publicacao.endereco as endereco,
       publicacao.tipo as tipo,
       publicacao.descricao as descricao,
       cidade.nome as nomecidade, publicacao.contato as contato
FROM `publicacao`
inner join usuario on publicacao.codUsuario = usuario.codUsuario
inner join cidade on publicacao.codcidade = cidade.codcidade
```

**Php:**

```
  $sql = "SELECT publicacao.codPublicacao as codpublicacao,usuario.nome as 
            nomeusuario, publicacao.categoria as categoria,
            publicacao.endereco as endereco, publicacao.tipo as tipo, 
            publicacao.descricao as descricao, cidade.nome as nomecidade,
            publicacao.contato as contato FROM `publicacao` inner join usuario on 
        publicacao.codUsuario = usuario.codUsuario inner join cidade on 
    publicacao.codcidade = cidade.codcidade"; 
                        $result = $conn->query($sql);
                    $encode = array();

                     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                       $encode[] = json_encode($row);

                    }
echo json_encode($encode);

?>
```

Comment: Isso tentado é API, pequise sobre **json_encode** o link http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php e tem outro jeito facil api é usar programa chama GO

Comment: Porque não usa `json_encode();` nos resultados (linhas) retornados da BD?

Comment: Eu usei o json_encode($vetor) (não sei se está correto) mas ele não retornar nada, a pagina fica em branco, porem quando uso um select simples, ele aparece o json

Comment: Você pode fornecer a estrutura das tabelas junto com dados em um arquivo SQL pra teste?

Comment: Diego, é cade **echo**? Não use while json_encode e para depois, `$encode = $row` e `echo json_encode($encode)` para sair o resultado da tela.

Comment: O banco de dados está aqui ->https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-aEUv85JPz2ZzdiZFAtTnJYN2M

Answer (score 0):

Por que você não usa deste modo?

```
while ($row = $result->fetchAll()) {
    $encode[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($encode);
```

Mesmo do modo anterior estava retornando corretamente o json,mas assim já basta.

Se não der certo, olhe o log de erro, talvez esteja estourando a memoria do php.

Comment: não consegui localizar essa função fetchAll(), pelo oque eu pesquisei ela tá obsoleta
o erro : Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetchAll()

Comment: Fiz utilizando PDO, mas pode manter seu fetch_assoc